# How to join threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

My main thread starts multiple threads which serve http and grpc endpoints.

main thread

```
s1 = Server1()
s2 = Server2()
```

Server1 and Server2 are classes similar to

```
class Server1(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, service):
    super().__init__()
    self.grpcServer(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    self.grpcServer.add_insecure_port('[::]:8000')
    myservice_pb2_grpc.add_MyServiceServicer_to_server(service, self.grpcServer)

  def run(self):
    self.grpcserver.start()
    self.grpcServer.wait_for_termination()
```

Now I'd like to modify this so if any of the parallel thread exits (any type of fault in the servers), the main thread and application exit too. (The application exiting would cause its docker container to exit, which would be detected by Kubernetes which would restart the pod, much better than leaving that container running with an application that has one dead endpoint that nobody knows about until someone tries to use that endpoint)

I thought of using [thread-objects' join method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

add the following to the main thread:

```
s1.join()
s2.join()
```

But that does not work, I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'` at `s1.join()`. I don't do a lot of Python, so I'm sure this is a silly misunderstanding, I just don't see it.

Comment: `s1` is `None`. Check what they are assigned to.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. s1 is assigned to Server1() at `s1 = Server1()`. I would assume this means s1 is of type a class that derives from threading.Thread, and as such the join method can be called on s1. Guess I'm wrong, but why?

Comment: Well the interpreter says it's `None`, you assume it's not. Unluckily for you the interpreter is the one running the code. Show us all relevant code!

Comment: if `s1` were indeed assigned as `Server1()` you would get a different error since you have not passed the `service` argument to `Server1()`. Clearly there is something missing that is not there in the question right now.

Comment: I guess that you somehow mixed a global variable (can exist outside and inside of functions) and local variable (only inside function) of the same name. Your code samples are too small to tell if I'm right or not. More context is needed.

Comment: You are right, your comments had me look more closely at the `s1 = Server1()` line which is a long multiline with several arguments, including the service, and actually the that line can be summerized as `s1 = Server1().start()`. That start method call was the culprit. Thank you.